# install Pyaudio - whl

Tags: python, installation, pip, pyaudio, python-wheel

I tried to install PyAudio on Windows 7 64bit.
Installing it with pip throws dependency errors which end up in the question how to satisfy those.
So i tried to install it with wheel, the suggestion was to just use pip install:

```
D:\Programming\Kivy>dir
...
27.03.2015  08:11           113.556 PyAudio.whl

D:\Programming\Kivy>pip install PyAudio.whl
Downloading/unpacking PyAudio.whl
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyAudio.whl
No distributions at all found for PyAudio.whl
Storing complete log in C:\Users\WindowsPro\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

Any suggestion how to install pyaudio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of pip do you have? Show the output `pip -V`. It might be necessary to have a current pip version 6 to install the whl. If this is not the case do `pip install --upgrade pip` (it might be necessary to start the console with admin rights).

Did you download the library from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio? I just installed this version with pip and it works.

As an alternative you can download the installer exe from http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#downloads and install it like a regular program.

Answer (score 1):

If you cant donwload it by **pip install pyaudio** you can download it from [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files).
When you found PyAudio, find the version of your Python (ex. 3.7.2 32bit).

**DOWNLOAD THE RIGHT VERSION.** Once you found the .whl of your python version, download it. Install it by opening cmd, going to the folder that you save it and write **pip install "pyaudio_whl_file.whl"**

And that's it

Comment: Why are you linking an external site for that module when you could provide the one from python's own repo?  More people would select that one!

Comment: J. Murray, If he can install it due to a conflict between applications, he can directly download the WHL

If not, then install it with pip