# PyAudio Wheel is Unsupported?

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyaudio, portaudio

PyAudio. It's been a well-known problem for a while now that when installing PyAudio, you can't do `pip install PyAudio`, because it will tell you that it couldn't find `portaudio.h`.

So, as you go on your journey to be taught by some Indian guy on YouTube, you realize that all the videos say the same thing: you have to manually install the wheel (https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files), by downloading it, then doing `pip install <path-to-wheel>`.

However, as of September 2019, this method no longer works. The command prompt will simply tell you that the wheel is unsupported, without any other information. And so far, there is nothing on the internet that I can find that will tell you how to fix this problem on a Windows machine. Is there some kind of work around?

(Python: 3.7.4, Pip: 19.2.3)

***EDIT:***

I will get back to this question soon, but my desktop is broken at the moment. Once I get it back up and running, I will test whatever suggestions are in the comments/answers sections.

Comment: The linked page doesn't list wheels for Python 3.7. Only 2.7, 3.4-3.6 are available for downloads. Either you have to find a different wheel, or use a different Python, or compile from sources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [install Pyaudio - whl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295494/install-pyaudio-whl)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+%5Bpyaudio%5D

Comment: Maybe it was flagged by one person, but it was not marked as duplicate by others, so you're good!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *phd* already commented...

From the [*PyAudio* documentation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#downloads):

> Currently, there are wheels compatible with the official distributions of Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. For those versions, both 32-bit and 64-bit wheels are available.

You are running *Python 3.7.4*, there is **no *wheel* available for this version**. The exact same thing is perfectly visible on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/0.2.11/#files): there is **no wheel available for the Python version `cp37`**.

You will have to either pick a compatible version of Python or compile the *wheel* yourself.

If you feel adventurous, you could try the [`--python-version` option of `pip install`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-python-version) and the other associated options. I would not recommend it though.

---

There are some wheels available on this 3rd party website:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Answer (score 1):

if you're on win 10, these are the steps I used to make it work:

1. ddl visual studio code 14 (c++)
2. pip install pipwin
3. pipwin install pyaudio