# Can't install PyAudio from PyPI wheel files

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyaudio

I want to make a speech recognition program using SpeechRecognition, which needs PyAudio to work.

I tried installing it with `pip`, but it says that `portaudio.h` is missing. So I went on PyPI and downloaded a `.whl` file from there (https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files). But no matter what file with what version or what platform I download, `pip` just keeps saying that the wheel is not supported.

First try:

```
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Second try:

```
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Third try:

```
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

There's also someone else who posted about the same problem ([PyAudio Wheel is Unsupported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028999/pyaudio-wheel-is-unsupported)), but didn't get any answers, that's why I posted my own.

PS. I checked my architecture, it's a Win32.

Comment: Are you sure your Python version is supported? "Currently, there are wheels compatible with the official distributions of Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. For those versions, both 32-bit and 64-bit wheels are available." -- http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#downloads

Comment: @sinoroc My version is 3.7, shouldn't it work with 3.6 and 3.5 versions ?

Comment: No it shouldn't. You could try `pip install --python-version 36 pyaudio`, but I wouldn't recommend it, I have little confidence that it would work.

Answer (score 0):

There are some wheels built by a third party here:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Answer (score -2):

I finally found a solution. I used a tool named `pipwin`, it's like `pip` but the difference is that it installs all the necessary dependencies. It can easily be installed so :

```
pip install pipwin
```

And then :

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```